# postfix log file suddenly vanished on centos 6.4

Tags: centos, postfix-mta

I have just installed a CentOS 6.4 on a VPS running a test mail server with Postfix + Dovecot. Just after complete installing, I tried to reset the default postfix logfile under /var/log/maillog by:

> > # cp /dec/null /var/log/maillog
> >       # service postfix restart

but just after I restarted postfix, I found nothing is being written on to that /var/log/maillog, always shows 0 size, even tried to make mail errors.

> > # ls -al /var/log/maillog
> >      >>  -rw------- 1 root root 0 Oct 27 10:07 /var/log/maillog

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you all. I have just found that mail logs are being written by <em>rsyslog</em>, so that the above problem is solved by restarting rsyslog and postfix.

Comment: Thanks! I was having the same problem. rsyslog saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

Postfix doesn't write logs, it merely uses syslog()
This means you'll have to restart the syslog daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue with delete maillog file and   restart rsyslog service:

```
cd /var/log/
rm -f maillog
service rsyslog restart 
service postfix restart
```

source: http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/postfix/varlogmaillog-no-data-update-when-mail-incoming-and-outgoing/

Comment: Thank you!
I have already solved this quite before. Appreciate your answer anyway. Thank you.